# How can I resolve my CGI error during installation of Drupal 7 on WinXp?

Tags: installation

I'm installing a local instance of Drupal 7 on my WinXp machine. PHP 5.4 and MySql 5.5 are installed already.

I've unpacked the downloaded Drupal 7 site files into a virtual directory and used IIS 6 to make this directory a PHP site.

However, the result is not encouraging:

> CGI Error The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a
>   complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are:
>
> Could not open input file: Files\PHP\php-win.exe

The web address I'm using is:

```
http://localhost/drupal7/install.php
```

Where "drupal7" is the name of my application in IIS.

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: If possible I'd switch to Apache instead of IIS

Comment: Apache on Windows?  Hmmm.  Can you even run Apache and IIS on the same machine?

Comment: Yuppers. http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache24

I do all my development with Apache 2.4, PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.5 on Windows XP.

Comment: Use XAMP, WAMP...

Comment: you could try using [WAMP server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [Acquia Dev Desktop](http://www.acquia.com/downloads). I would recomend using Acquia, as it contains all the necessary settings already configured.

Comment: @Ajit, you should put this comment into the question as an Answer.  I just got done installing Acquia Dev Desktop and got my Drupal site up and running with no problems whatsoever.  I'd like to Accept your comment as the Accepted Answer if I could.

Comment: @MikeClark Look for my [answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31791/having-problem-installing-drupal-7-on-winxp-getting-cgi-error/31928#31928). Also added another option of installing on windows which could be configured for IIS. Apache is mostly recommended though.

Answer (score 1):

As in my [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31791/having-problem-installing-drupal-7-on-winxp-getting-cgi-error#comment31569_31791) above, you should try using [WAMP server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [Acquia Dev Desktop](http://www.acquia.com/downloads), which uses Apache (more suitable for PHP development).

To install Drupal on Windows, you could install it with Microsoft web platform installer by following [this procedure](http://drupal.org/node/1130898).

Answer (score 0):

Commenters are right : try to use Apache.

About your error, my guess is a there is a path problem with the "Program Files" folder which contains a space which must not have been escaped correctly.

Did you try to change the place of your installation and/or correct the setting for the path to the php executable ?